# Custom server paging in asp.net with listview and datapager control

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, pagination, datapager

I have a listview control in a page and i want to do a custom server paging for the listview data. So instead of getting whole data and keeping in the memory, I would like to bring data in chunks and then bind the listview control.

For example:

If I request

http://www.mywebsite.com/getlistofdata.aspx?p=1, the first page come with 10 items
http://www.mywebsite.com/getlistofdata.aspx?p=2, the second page comes up with another 10 items
and likewise.

I have written a function **BindListView(int pageNumber, int pageSize, out int totalRowsCount)**
that returns me the data according to the page number and page size passed.

How can I make the Datapager work in this situation?

The problem is it shows one link to navigate for only one page, i need to populate the datapager according to the value of **totalRowsCount**.